# Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{k!}$ have a closed form solution?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{k!}$ have a closed form solution?

I am working on a greater question involving this infinite series and I have been struggling with thinking of ways to evaluate it. Currently, I am thinking an inductive argument may work, but even that seems futile.

Comment: The sum in your title is not an infinite series as specified in your question.  Perhaps you want the following? - $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^n}{k!}=eB_n\ ,$$where $B_n$ is the $n$th Bell number: [details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula)

Comment: This is indeed what I meant. I suppose I'm looking for more insight on the proof than the Wikipedia article provides

Answer (score 4):

For fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$, notice that each term in the sum has  $n$ copies of $k$ in the numerator where $n\geq k\geq 0$, but only $k$ numbers in the factorial product $k!=k\times (k-1)\times \ldots \times 1$ in the denominator where each of these positive numbers is $\leq k$. In other words, each term in the sum is $\geq 1$ (you can verify this by induction), so $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{k!}\geq n,$$ and so the limit goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: You explained it so simply, thank you. This is still a useful result, since the greater problem involves uncountably many things. I think this may push me further in one direction. Thanks again!

Comment: @Solve_for_T Glad I could help.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The question has been edited. The question originally had the sum running up to $n$, so $k\leq n$ was always true.

Comment: Ah, OK. My bad, and bad on the OP to change the question. Didn't check edit history.

Comment: That is my fault -- sorry! It is late and I should go to bed...

Comment: @Solve_for_T No worries.